# Returning a reference vs. a copy from a C++ method

Tags: c++, reference

I'm currently learning C++, and am a bit confused about the concept of returning a reference from a method. Consider the following toy example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class IntHolder {

private:

    std::vector<int> d_values;

public:

    IntHolder() {
        d_values.push_back(1);
        d_values.push_back(2);
        d_values.push_back(3);
    }

    std::vector<int> &values() {
        return d_values;
    }

};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    IntHolder h;
    std::vector<int> ret_val = h.values();
    std::cout << ret_val.size() << std::endl;

    ret_val.push_back(4);
    ret_val.push_back(5);

    std::cout << h.values().size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This prints the following to the standard output:

```
3
3
```

Since we are returning a reference to `d_values`, shouldn't the object returned be the same that is stored in the instance of `IntHolder`, and thus when calling `h.values()` again, we should see a size of 5?

Since this is not the case, what is the difference between *returning* a reference to an object or a copy of the object? Is there a difference when you are returning from a method?

Answer (score 3):

You are *returning* a reference from the `values` function, but you are not *assigning* that returned object to a reference variable. Instead, you are making a *copy* of it because you are assigning it to a new `std::vector<int>` named `ret_val`.

You want to modify your code like so, in order to capture the returned reference:

```
std::vector<int>& ret_val = h.values();
```

Or perhaps simply:

```
auto& ret_val = h.values();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method is returning a reference, but you are then assigning the result to another vector, causing a copy.  To fix this, change your `ret_val` definition to:

```
std::vector<int> & ret_val = h.values();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return a reference, you return the same object and you are not creating a copy. Basically it seems that it is just as you did expect it:

```
std::cout << h.values().size() << std::endl;
h.values().push_back(4);
h.values().push_back(5);
std::cout << h.values().size() << std::endl;
```

Would return

```
3
5
```

---

The misstage is another one. Let's look at

```
std::vector<int> ret_val = h.values();
```

You discovered that `ret_val` is a copy of `h.d_values` while `h.values()` is returning a reference to it. We could rewrite your code above as follows:

```
std::vector<int> &ret_ref = h.values(); // object returned by `h.values()`
std::vector<int>  ret_val = ret_ref;
```

If you are calling `ret_ref.push_back(4)`, `h.d_values` would change. But `ret_val` is a copy of the returned object and will not affect `h.d_values`.